# C forever Loop after return from a sub function

Tags: c, loops, return

I have a function parse, which I am calling in the main,
it reads the 2D array expense row one by one, if the total columns in any Row of expense are not equal to 5, it returns 1 and prints an error. but it's stuck in a forever loop. Since I am very new to c, I am unable to figure it out.

```
int parse (char* exp, char* exp_str) {
    char d[] = " ";
    char *cpyexp;
    
    strcpy(cpyexp, exp);
    
    printf("cpyexp %s \n", cpyexp);
    printf("strlen(cpyexp) %lu \n", strlen(cpyexp));
    
    if(strlen(cpyexp) != 9)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error1: parse() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }    

    return 0; 
 }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    char* file = NULL ;
    char  expenses [ROWS][COLS] = {{"CAR,14,10"},{"INS,10,12"}} ;
    char  expenses_str [ROWS][17] ;     

    int i = 0; 
    while(expenses[i][0] != '\0' ){
        if(parse (expenses[i], expenses_str[i]) == 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error3: parse_instruction() failed\n");
            return 1;  
        }

        if (expenses[i]== NULL || expenses[i] == '\0'){
            break; 
        }       
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(cpyexp, exp);` Your compiler should warn you about using `cpyexp` without initializing it. That pointer does not point to any valid memory.

Comment: `if (expenses[i]== NULL || expenses[i] == '\0')` here `expenses[i]` is an array. An array (unless dynamically allocated) can never be `NULL`. Also `NULL` and `\0` are basically identical.

Comment: `{{"CAR",4,10},{"INS", 10,12}} ;` How is this supposed to match a 2D char array?

Comment: With all that mentioned, your compiler should scream in pain. Read your warnings. Fix them. Do not run your code until you are done with that. Increase warning level. For clang or GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Gerhard, this is been read from a file, each string looks like CAR1410 OR 1NS1012

Comment: No, that is completely wrong. These are not strings. If you want to provide hard coded strings, use strings! Not some structs of strings and numbers.

Comment: Correct initializers would be `{"CAR1410", "INS1012"}`, then. But with these strings, `cpyexpr` will never be 5 characters long.

Comment: I changed my initialization

Answer (score -2):

```
int parse (char* exp, char* exp_str) {
    char d[] = " ";
    char *cpyexp  =malloc(strlen(exp)+1)* sizeof(char)) \\this is initialized as NULL and hats why getting an error
    
    strcpy(cpyexp, exp);
    
    printf("cpyexp %s \n", cpyexp);
    printf("strlen(cpyexp) %lu \n", strlen(cpyexp));
    
    if(strlen(cpyexp) != 9)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error1: parse() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }    

    return 0; 
 }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    char* file = NULL ;
    char  expenses [ROWS][COLS] = {{"CAR,14,10"},{"INS,10,12"}} ;
    char  expenses_str [ROWS][17] ;     

    int i = 0; 
    while(expenses[i][0] != '\0' ){
        if(parse (expenses[i], expenses_str[i]) == 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error3: parse_instruction() failed\n");
            return 1;  
        }

        if (expenses[i]== NULL || expenses[i] == '\0'){
            break; 
        }       
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be the solution? What did you change, why? Code-only answers are considered low quality at StackOverflow. You might want to edit to add an explanation. Or is this still showing an error? Then this should not be an answer at all but go into the question.

Comment: `malloc(strlen(exp)+1)* sizeof(char)) \\this is initialized as NULL` The brackets are messed up and the comment is also wrong. This does not compile. Use copy&paste of code you actually compile, don't retype it. How do you know if that is `NULL`? You do not check the return value. BTW: You do not free the memory and you do not use it after that function, that creates a memory leak.